# Correct message for ASP.NET MVC client side Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

In **ASP.NET MVC** it is very easy to validate the data that a user typed in a textbox. By Adding the following line we ask from the framework to display an error message when the user types something wrong.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

In my application I want this functionality but I also want to display a message when the user typed a ***correct information***.  Is there any html helper like the `ValidationMessageFor` which will display a message to inform the user that the typed information ***is correct***?

Comment: Is there any example somewhere of how to do it myself?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I suggest you explore the `jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js` file to see how and when error messages are added/removed and modify the code to suit. I also suggest that doing this would be a sure way annoy the users of your site (I for one would not come back if you keep displaying annoying messages telling me what I already know is correct)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only simple cases of client validation you can try to change your **css**. **Unobtrusive validation** library set `valid` **class** to fields which is valid.

So you can change your css like this:

```
input.valid, select.valid, textarea.valid{
   border-color: green;
}
```

More complex cases, that need server participation, can only be achived if you send **AJAX call** on field change.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. This is not the best solution but it works. I am going to write it here because more people may need it.

I created a timer and I check every X milliseconds all the validated properties of the model and if the error message of the specified property has the class 'field-validation-valid', this means that the property the user has typed is valid so I show the valid error message. Otherwise I hide it.

In the view I have added a div which contains the message for the valid field which has an id equal to ValidNameFor followed by the name of the property.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div id="ValidNameForSurname">This is correct</div>
```

The javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function ()
    {
        $(".form-control").each(function () {
            var confirmSpan = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");
            if (confirmSpan.hasClass("field-validation-valid")) 
                $("#ValidNameFor" + $(this).attr('id')).show();
            else
                $("#ValidNameFor" + $(this).attr('id')).hide();
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

A way to remove the timer would be to have a jQuery event which will inform me when a class has been added or removed from an element. If there was such an event I could remove the timer and show or hide the correct text when the class 'field-validation-valid' has been added to the validated property. If someone knows how to add such event to an element it would be nice to know.

Answer (score -1):

You could use whether or not the validation message is showing as a condition upon which to base showing your confirmation with onfocusout as your trigger. So given some html like this:

```
<form id="myFrm" action="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">            <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
   <hr />
   <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control myFrmInputs" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
               <span id="confirmEmail" class="confirmationMessage">Correct</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control myFrmInputs" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            <span id="confirmPassword" class="confirmationMessage">Correct</span>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Some CSS like so:

```
.confirmationMessage {
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript / jquery

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".myFrmInputs").each(function() {            
                $(this).focusout(function() {
                   //var errorSpan = $("#myFrm span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");
                   var errorSpan = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-error");
                   if (errorSpan.length>0 && !$(errorSpan).is(":visible")) 
                   {
                       $("#confirm" + $(this).attr('id')).show();
                   }
                });    
            });
    });
```

You can display a confirmation based solely on whether the input has not been tagged as invalid. This is only for text inputs but you can jimmy the method for other input types. It's hardly production ready but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/f55xsLjx/1/

Comment: This will fail for a number of reasons. (1) Unobtrusive validation is lazy so when a user tabs though controls, the "correct" mesage will display even if its not correct (2) The element you refer to as `confirmSpan` is always visible - unobtrusive validation adds another `span` element inside it - so the message would never display (3) There is no guarantee that the unobtrusive validation message will have been added/removed when this check is performed

Comment: @StephenMuecke (1) If by lazy you mean nulls/empties then you're right, but i'll leave it to the op to decide what he/she wants to do there, could simply be another condition on pre-show, (2) was thinking this was add-remove class but no it's a span so edited answer, (3) op needs to put this attachment code after call <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script> for order of execution.

Comment: No, your misunderstanding some basics of how unobtrusive validation works. If you have a form with a few `string` properties with `[Required]` and just tab through the controls, validation is not triggered so your code would display "Correct" despite the fact its not. Validation is not triggered until you actually make a change (that's what I mean by _lazy_).

Comment: Next, validation is triggered when the control loses focus, which is when you code is also triggered. Most likely your code will complete before validation message is added (but no guarantee) so again you will display "Correct" but the error message will also be displayed (somewhat confusing). But in any case, OP has not really thought this through. Imagine a control asking for your name or address and you make a typo. Now you know you have made a mistake, but you get a message saying "Correct" :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that tab through equals "correct" for empty fields so he can just put in an extra conditional as per (1) . The rest of what you said re:timing I disagree with since the handlers are synchronous and  are run in the order they are attached.